# Mock a method which takes an argument of T type and returns the same type T

Tags: junit, mockito

I have a method in a class, code below, which takes two argument of type let say `String` and a `T`. and this methods returns `T`. Now, I have to mock this method. But whenever I am trying this with Mokito getting `TypeMismatch` error.

```
Class ImplementationClass {
    .
    .
    public T someMethod(String arg0, T arg2) {
        .
        .
        return T;
    }

}
```

I would like to get the return type of method should be type of argument passed into it, i.e. T in this case.

Comment: Your code is not valid Java code. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as well as the exact and complete error you get.

Answer (score 0):

im sorry, but i dont understand your problem.

1. if `someMethod(...)` "only" changes the `Object` of `Type` `T`, that is passed via parameter to it, there is no need to return a it, cause JAVA passes its reference into `someMethod(...)`
2. i think you have to mock your `Object` of `Type` `T`, dont you? cause, in my mind, you want to call your `someMethod(...)` in your unit-test

**Edit**

as long as you pass an `Object` of `Type` `T` into `someMethod(..)` and assign its return-value to something of `Type` `T`, it should work fine